# Virtual Equal Function on C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, virtual, equality

I am trying to do something like:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() = default;
    ~A() = default;

public:
    bool operator==(const A& a)
    {
        return this->equal(a);
    };

private:
    virtual bool equal(const A& other) const = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() = default;
    ~B() = default;

private:
    virtual bool equal(const A& other) const override
    {
        const B* b = dynamic_cast<const B*>(&other);
        if (!b)
            return false;
        
        return m_example == b->m_example;
    }

private:
    double m_example; //This is just an example data I don't need specific solution for double :)
};
```

Goal: Only equality possible is between classes of same type = B.

1. Is that ok?
2. Is there a standard solution to have a virtual equal operator?
3. I will be inherting from A a lot (4/8 classes), how can I do this in a clean way, the check if the pointer is null looks very ugly.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Totally unrelated: Once a function is marked `virtual`, it stays `virtual`. The derived classes can leave `virtual` out. But keep an eye out for `final`.

Comment: Does [virtual operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30638634/virtual-operator-overloading-c) answer part of the question?

Answer (score 3):

It's a matter of opinion whether dynamic casts are ugly, or not. It's an endless debate, but it doesn't matter here. That's because dynamic casts are not needed here. This can be done, cleanly, using inheritance:

```
class B; // Forward declaration.

class A {

   // Same as above

private:
   virtual bool equal(const A& other) const = 0;
   virtual bool equal(const B& other) const { return false; }
};

// ... B class:

    bool equal(const A& other) const override
    {
        return other.equal(*this);
    }

    bool equal(const B &other) const override
    {        
        return m_example == other.m_example;
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't `B::equal(const A& other)` use `other` somewhere?

Comment: Yup, fixed now.

Comment: Thanks very much! As I said in my question I will have 8 classes inheriting from A, I will have to add 8 “equal” functions to each class each class including the base class? Or each class will have only two equal functions and the base class having 8 equal function? Sorry I couldn’t generalise your code, I fail to do it if many classes inherit from A or for example another class C inherits from B :) Please help if you can.

Comment: Why would you think that class `B` will need to implement `equal()` for class `C`? What could it possibly to do, except to return `false`, exactly like the default implementation in the base class, which does the same thing. Of course not. Only the base class needs to define the default implementation of `equal()`, for each subclass, and each subclass implements two overrides, one for `A` and one for itself.

Comment: All clear Sir! Thanks very much!!

Comment: I think my question has been answered and maybe I should open a new one (Please let me know Admins). But this is very interesting: What if B is templated? I have to implement all template specialization in class A or there is a workaround please?

Comment: You should ask a new question, and include a specific example of what you're asking about. This is getting into a level of vastly increasing complexity, with many possible variations, i.e., should different templates be comparable, in some common way (all template instances have `m_example`, for example), or should all of them be different, or anywhere in between...

Comment: Actually you are right, just realized the variations after you mentioned it. I have to think this through first. Thanks!

Comment: I asked a follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71805026/virtual-equal-function-between-templated-classes-c). Please help if you can :)