Why is dynamic dispatch not working within a template function?
I have the following code. There is a base class (Node) and a derived class (NumberExprNode) that each have a virtual equality method.
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
bool operator==(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>& n1, const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>& n2) {
  std::cout << "Called std::vector equality check" << std::endl;
  if (n1.size() != n2.size()) {
     return false;
   }
   for (size_t i = 0; i < n1.size(); i++) {
    if (!(*n1[i] == *n2[i])) {
      return false;
    }
  }
return true;
}

class Node {
public:
  virtual bool operator==(const Node& other) const {
    std::cout << "Called Node equality check" << std::endl;
    return false;
  }
};

class NumberExprNode : public Node {
  double Val;

public:
  virtual bool operator==(const NumberExprNode& other) const __attribute__((used)) {
    std::cout << "Called NumberExprNode equality check" << std::endl;
    return (Val == other.Val);
  }

  NumberExprNode(double val) : Val(val) {}
};

int main() {
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> n_vec1; // Base class Node used here
  n_vec1.emplace_back(std::make_unique<NumberExprNode>(5));
  n_vec1.emplace_back(std::make_unique<NumberExprNode>(6));
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> n_vec2;  // Base class Node used here
  n_vec2.emplace_back(std::make_unique<NumberExprNode>(5));
  n_vec2.emplace_back(std::make_unique<NumberExprNode>(6));
  return (n_vec1 == n_vec2);
}

I see the following printed to stdout:
Called std::vector equality check
Called Node equality check

But if I replace 'main' with:
int main() {
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<NumberExprNode>> n_vec1; // Derived class used here
  n_vec1.emplace_back(std::make_unique<NumberExprNode>(5));
  n_vec1.emplace_back(std::make_unique<NumberExprNode>(6));
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<NumberExprNode>> n_vec2; // Derived class used here
  n_vec2.emplace_back(std::make_unique<NumberExprNode>(5));
  n_vec2.emplace_back(std::make_unique<NumberExprNode>(6));
  return (n_vec1 == n_vec2);

then I see
Called std::vector equality check
Called NumberExprNode equality check
Called NumberExprNode equality check

printed to stdout, which is what I wanted.
I find this counterintuitive. The entries of n_vec1 each point to objects initialized with the derived class. And I think that the derived class instances have an intact vtable. I stepped through in GDB and printed *n1[i] and *n2[i]. I observed that they each had a vtable for NumberExprNode. So I conclude that even the first example should properly dispatch to the NumberExprNode overridden operator==. Yet is it not. Why is this?
Taking a look at the bigger picture, for my application I want to be able to take in a heterogeneous std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> where each entry could point to a different derived class. I want the equality operator to properly dispatch to the correct operator== method that corresponds to the class that was used to initialize the object. How can I rework/restructure my code to accomplish this?

bool operator==(const NumberExprNode& other) const doesn't override bool operator==(const Node& other) const. If you used override keyword, that much would be clear.

For this to work, you need a "double dispatch" where both sides of the equal sign are using its own vtable. That is not what happens.

Related (see the top voted answer, not the accepted one): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30638634/virtual-operator-overloading-c

The obvious problem is that your virtual operator== doesn't override...

You could, conceivably, try something like this:
class NumberExprNode : public Node {
  double Val;

public:
  virtual bool operator==(const Node& other_) const override {
    std::cout << "Called NumberExprNode equality check" << std::endl;
    const auto& other=dynamic_cast<const NumberExprNode&>(other_);
    return (Val == other.Val);
  }

  NumberExprNode(double val) : Val(val) {}
};

so the operator== actually overrides the other operator==:
stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ g++ Test.cpp; ./a.out
Called std::vector equality check
Called NumberExprNode equality check
Called NumberExprNode equality check

However, the above will throw if you compare a NumberExprNode with just a Node since the cast will fail:
int main() {
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> n_vec1; // Base class Node used here
  n_vec1.emplace_back(std::make_unique<NumberExprNode>(5));
  n_vec1.emplace_back(std::make_unique<NumberExprNode>(6));
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> n_vec2;  // Base class Node used here
  n_vec2.emplace_back(std::make_unique<NumberExprNode>(5));
  n_vec2.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Node>());
  return (n_vec1 == n_vec2);
}

stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ g++ Test.cpp; ./a.out
Called std::vector equality check
Called NumberExprNode equality check
Called NumberExprNode equality check
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_cast'
  what():  std::bad_cast
Aborted

So, you could try something like this:
class NumberExprNode : public Node {
  double Val;

public:
  virtual bool operator==(const Node& other_) const override {
    std::cout << "Called NumberExprNode equality check" << std::endl;
    if (auto other=dynamic_cast<const NumberExprNode*>(&other_))
    {
        return (Val == other->Val);
    }
    else
    {
        return Node::operator==(other_);
    }
  }

  NumberExprNode(double val) : Val(val) {}
};

Which would allow the test to work with all combinations -- however, my concern here is that I don't remember actually doing that anywhere, since it's basically an attempt to implement a comparison of distinct classes.

always a problem of choosing between is-a and has-a. Often class should follow liskov principle, but a built-in operator comparing two different types is non-ideomatic and potentially error-prone.  Comparison of different types should be external or self-contained (e.g. via CRTP)
